# ActionBar buttons maintaining 'pressed' state, possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app that in a certain `Activity` (drawing) can be in any one of a number of states, such as draw, erase, select, etc.

To enable these states, I've got a button for each in the `ActionBar`, but one thing I'd like to do is to 'show' the user which state is enabled by keeping the button pressed active or pressed until I turn it off (when they have switched state by pressing one of the other buttons).

Searches here and other places have me coming up blank... can anyone recommend a possible solution? I've though about rolling my own toolbar, and while this might be my final solution, using the ActionBar would speed things up greatly at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that, as far as I know, but you could implement your custom component to do that. However, my advice to you is having a separate toolbar that's not on the action bar, since the users expect all buttons on the Action Bar to be "Action Items" which perform something immediate, so having toggle items on the Action Bar might break this expectation. This allows you to save space on the action bar for things that the user expects to see there like: navigation, "Undo", "Save", "Delete"...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking as a long-term solution, but prototyping some features and was hoping for something quick and dirty.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with putting a toggle button in the action button.  Google uses them in the gmail app for honeycomb and above.  I am looking into implementing this myself.

Comment: Don't think that the user expect action button to be just button. Custom views are very useful and very common like searchview for instance. Toggle button can also be considered as action.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bruno about the fact its probably best if you do it in a separate toolbar for the sake of user experience standard and your code will probably look better because you cant fully customize the action bar but if you do decide to go with it i can think of something really simple like, when clicking one of the menu buttons you set the pressed button to a new drawable (pressed button) and the others to their normal drawable (not pressed) so each menu icon will have a pressed and not pressed icon. you will have to `invalidateOptionsMenu` though.

Comment: Interesting. This might work for the short-term, but I agree about needing to have a custom solution long-term.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find a solution. However, I found a workaround that works for me:

In the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method, if `item` is the button you want to toggle, simply call `item.setIcon()` and point to another drawable. I use the same image but with another color to show the user that the button is in "pressed" state. And when the button is pressed again, revert to the original drawable.